# E: Failed to fetch 404 <URL> Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.174 80] error when I run apt-get update

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates

When I execute the `sudo apt-get update` command, I'm encountering with the following error:

> E: Failed to fetch
>   http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-arm64/Packages
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
>
> E: Failed to fetch
>   http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
>
> E: Failed to fetch
>   http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.174 80]
>
> E: Failed to fetch
>   http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-arm64/Packages
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

I don't know if it's relevant but the contents of my `/etc/apt/source.list` file is as follows:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20190227)]/ xenial main res$

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiver$
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe mu$

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
#deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports trusty-updates universe
```

Ultimately I'm trying to install the `gtk-doc-tools` package with

```
sudo apt-get install -y gtk-doc-tools
```

which upon execution throws the following error:

> Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 xsltproc amd64 1.1.28-2.1ubuntu0.2
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
>
> Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 xsltproc amd64 1.1.28-2.1ubuntu0.2
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
>
> E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxslt/xsltproc_1.1.28-2.1ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

My PC specs are:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 142
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7600U CPU @ 2.80GHz
Stepping:              9
CPU MHz:               800.052
CPU max MHz:           3900.0000
CPU min MHz:           400.0000
BogoMIPS:              5808.00
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              4096K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

*Edit 1:*

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ ls -l
total 100
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   38 Nov 19  2017 cuda-9-0-local.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   92 Jun 23 11:13 cuda_learn.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   80 Jun 23 11:12 cuda.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  189 Jun 23 11:09 google-chrome.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  189 Jun 23 11:09 google-chrome.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  219 Jun 23 11:09 graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  144 Jun 23 11:09 graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  201 Jun 23 11:09 ozmartian-ubuntu-apps-xenial.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  201 Jun 23 11:09 ozmartian-ubuntu-apps-xenial.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  128 Jun 23 11:09 pj-assis-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  128 Jun 23 11:09 pj-assis-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   51 Jun 23 11:09 ros-latest.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   51 Jun 23 11:09 ros-latest.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   56 Nov 21 17:34 skype-stable.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   56 Jun 23 11:09 skype-stable.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  193 Sep  9 09:34 slack.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1198 Jun 23 11:09 teamviewer.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1198 Jun 23 11:09 teamviewer.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  150 Jun 23 11:09 ubuntu-toolchain-r-ubuntu-test-xenial.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  150 Jun 23 11:09 ubuntu-toolchain-r-ubuntu-test-xenial.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   74 Dec  1  2017 visionworks-repo.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   82 Nov 21  2017 visionworks-sfm-repo.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   92 Nov 21  2017 visionworks-tracking-repo.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  193 Jun 23 11:09 vscode.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  193 Jun 23 11:09 vscode.list.save
```

*Edit 2:*

When I run `~$ sudo dpkg --remove-architecture arm64` I get

> dpkg: error: cannot remove architecture 'arm64' currently in use by
>   the database

Additional information:

```
~$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
arm64
~$ dpkg --print-architecture
amd64
```

Then I ran `dpkg -l | grep arm64` and got:

```
ii  cpp-aarch64-linux-gnu                           4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1                                            amd64        GNU C preprocessor (cpp) for the arm64 architecture
ii  cuda-cublas-cross-aarch64-9-0:arm64             9.0.252-1                                                   arm64        CUBLAS cross-aarch64 dev links, headers
ii  cuda-cudart-cross-aarch64-9-0:arm64             9.0.252-1                                                   arm64        CUDA Runtime cross-aarch64 dev links, headers
ii  cuda-cufft-cross-aarch64-9-0:arm64              9.0.252-1                                                   arm64        CUFFT cross-aarch64 dev links, headers
ii  cuda-curand-cross-aarch64-9-0:arm64             9.0.252-1                                                   arm64        CURAND cross-aarch64 dev links, headers
ii  cuda-cusolver-cross-aarch64-9-0:arm64           9.0.252-1                                                   arm64        CUSOLVER cross-aarch64 dev links, headers
ii  cuda-cusparse-cross-aarch64-9-0:arm64           9.0.252-1                                                   arm64        CUSPARSE cross-aarch64 dev links, headers
ii  cuda-driver-cross-aarch64-9-0:arm64             9.0.252-1                                                   arm64        CUDA Driver cross-aarch64 dev links, headers
ii  cuda-misc-headers-cross-aarch64-9-0:arm64       9.0.252-1                                                   arm64        CUDA headers for cross-aarch64
ii  cuda-npp-cross-aarch64-9-0:arm64                9.0.252-1                                                   arm64        NPP cross-aarch64 dev links, headers
ii  cuda-nvgraph-cross-aarch64-9-0:arm64            9.0.252-1                                                   arm64        NVGRAPH cross-aarch64 dev links, headers
ii  cuda-nvml-cross-aarch64-9-0:arm64               9.0.252-1                                                   arm64        NVML cross-aarch64 dev links, headers
ii  cuda-nvrtc-cross-aarch64-9-0:arm64              9.0.252-1                                                   arm64        NVRTC cross-aarch64 dev links, headers
ii  g++-aarch64-linux-gnu                           4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1                                            amd64        GNU C++ compiler for the arm64 architecture
ii  gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu                           4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1                                            amd64        GNU C compiler for the arm64 architecture
ii  libasan2-arm64-cross                            5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9cross1                                all          AddressSanitizer -- a fast memory error detector
ii  libatomic1-arm64-cross                          5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9cross1                                all          support library providing __atomic built-in functions
ii  libc6-arm64-cross                               2.23-0ubuntu3cross1                                         all          GNU C Library: Shared libraries (for cross-compiling)
ii  libc6-dev-arm64-cross                           2.23-0ubuntu3cross1                                         all          GNU C Library: Development Libraries and Header Files (for cross-compiling)
ii  libgcc-5-dev-arm64-cross                        5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9cross1                                all          GCC support library (development files)
ii  libgcc1-arm64-cross                             1:5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9cross1                              all          GCC support library
ii  libgomp1-arm64-cross                            5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9cross1                                all          GCC OpenMP (GOMP) support library
ii  libitm1-arm64-cross                             5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9cross1                                all          GNU Transactional Memory Library
ii  libstdc++-5-dev-arm64-cross                     5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9cross1                                all          GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)
ii  libstdc++6-arm64-cross                          5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9cross1                                all          GNU Standard C++ Library v3
ii  libubsan0-arm64-cross                           5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9cross1                                all          UBSan -- undefined behaviour sanitizer (runtime)
ii  linux-libc-dev-arm64-cross                      4.4.0-18.34cross1                                           all          Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
```

If you need additional information, please let me know and I will provide it ASAP. Thanks!

Comment: Are you connected  to internet? You can't connect to Ubuntu repositories. Or you are behind some firewall or proxy.

Comment: @Pilot6 I tried to install the same package (gst-doc-tools) on a different Linux machine connected to the same internet network and it's installed successfully.

Comment: @Pilot6 the arm64 are [not avalable](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/)

Comment: I don't see `arm64` in `sources.list`? Where does it come from?

Comment: @Pilot6 I was wondering the same thing. I honestly don't know. I copied the entire file.

Comment: Maybe inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/<some file>`

Comment: @guillermochamorro Please see my *Edit 1*

Comment: Placed in the directory run the command: `grep "arm64" . -R`, let' see if the offending lines are there or not.

Comment: @guillermochamorro When I run this command in `/etc/apt/source.list.d`, there isn't anything matching with "arm64".

Comment: @Terrance please see my *Edit 2*.

Comment: I can see why you might have cross compiling platform, but your system itself does not support the arm64 architecture.  Maybe look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/295243/111521 and remove those files for now so your system stops looking at the arm64 sources that doesn't exist.